# PHP update ALL users based on condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've made a sports picks website and I can't figure out how to update ALL users scores based on their SPECIFIC picks they've made. I have to update one user at a time and fire the same script multiple times. (script fires when I log in then I restrict it from firing again)

--In this example I can only update the user 'robert'. I have a php file with an include file that contains a function--

Any help I can get would be greatly appreciated!!!

PHP file:

```
<?php


$connect = //connect to database

//ACCESS PERMISSION
$sql = "SELECT * FROM access WHERE username = 'bj'";

$query = mysql_query($sql,$connect);

if ($query) {

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $activated = $row['sf'];

if($activated=='1')
{
//END ACCESS PERMISSION EXCEPT CLOSE
//loop declare begin
$quer = "SELECT * FROM sffedorvsdan WHERE username = 'robert'";

if($quer_run = mysql_query($quer))
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quer_run))
    {
    $pick1 = $row['pick1'];
    $pick2 = $row['pick2'];
    $pick3 = $row['pick3'];
    $pick4 = $row['pick4'];
    $pick5 = $row['pick5'];
    $pick6 = $row['pick6']; 

//loop end EXCEPT CLOSE 



include('update2.php');

//PICK 1 START
more($pick1);

//PICK 2 START
more($pick2);

//PICK 3 START
more($pick3);

//PICK 4 START
more($pick4);

//PICK 5 START
more($pick5);

}
}else{
echo mysql_error();
}




//RESTRICT ACCESS
mysql_query("UPDATE access SET sf ='2'
WHERE username = 'bj'");
}
}
}


?>
```

Include file that contains function

```
<?php

function more($pick)
{

global $connect, $pick1, $pick2, $pick3, $pick4, $pick5, $pick6 ;

//connect to database

if($pick=='11'||$pick=='22'||$pick=='13'||$pick=='14'||$pick=='25') //True Picks
{
$score = mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET score = (score + 10), mmascore = (mmascore + 10), mmawins = (mmawins + 1), mmagames = (mmagames + 1), wins = (wins + 1), games = (games + 1)
WHERE username = 'robert'");

return $score;
}
else if($pick=='21'||$pick=='12'||$pick=='23'||$pick=='24'||$pick=='15') //False Picks
{
$score2 = mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET score = (score - 5), mmascore = (mmascore - 5), mmagames = (mmagames + 1), games = (games + 1)
WHERE username = 'robert'");

return $score2;
}



}

?>
```

Comment: Why not just remove the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: If each user makes a specific pick wouldn't removing the WHERE clause update all the scores without considering the specific picks each user made? (I hope that makes sense. A little hard to explain)

Comment: So, what should happen if `pick1 = 11` AND `pick2=22` ? Or if `pick1=11` BUT `pick2=12` ? I mean what should happen with 2 or more correct (true) picks or 2 or more wrong (false) ones or 1 true and 1 false pick?

Comment: And why username is `'bj'` in one table and `'robert'` in the other?

Comment: 'bj' is the admin user that triggers the operations. At the end of the code I restrict the admin user 'bj' from being able to trigger the operations twice. For your second question, the first part of the if statement is for correct(true) picks so points will be added, and the second if statement is for wrong(false) picks so points would be subtracted.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE stats SET score = score + CASE 
WHEN username='robert' THEN -5
WHEN username='RiaD' THEN 100500
WHEN username='Shef' THEN 6514
ELSE 0 END
```